# How can we convert an *.aar file to *.war file to deploy on weblogic server?

Tags: jakarta-ee

We need to convert an .aar file to .war file to deploy on weblogic server ? Its urgent if any one has an idea on how to do it. Please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe You need to put .aar file into the WEB-INF/services folder of your war file, then you can deploy the war.